# Why I am unable to add Word,Excel, etc file directly inside our document libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration

I am working on newly created root communication site collection, but inside the default Documents document library and any newly added document libraries i did not get the options to directly add Word,Excel, etc files, here is how the menu looks like:-

[image]

Can any one advice? although i am assigned E3 license.

Answer (score 1):

This is because someone has added a custom template/content type which removes the default content types (Word, Excel, PowerPoint...) from the New menu.

If you remove the custom template/content type, the default options will be present.

Comment: yes you are correct. we have a custom content type for our document libraries.. so we can not have a custom content type and at the same time create online office documents?

Comment: are you able to advice more on my above comment please?